# Data model for enum with associated values

Tags: ios, core-data, enums, relationship

I'm trying to figure out what's the recommended way to implement enum with associated values in Core Data data model. Let's say I have a book entity and I want to save in database how I got the book, like:

- it's bought by me (or other family members)
- it's borrowed from someone (e.g., a colleague)
- it's given as a gift by someone (e.g., a friend)

This would be an enum in swift:

```
enum WhereItCameFrom {
    case Bought(who: String, date: Date, where: String)
    case Borrorwed(who: String, date: Date, dueDate: Date)
    case GivenAsGift(who: String, date: Date, forWhat: String)
}
```

I'm thinking to implement it in data model using inheritance , as below:

- Introduce a parent entity `WhereItCameFrom` and define the above cases as its children entities.
- Define a `to-one` relationship from `Book` to `WhereItCameFrom`. Its deletion rule is `Cascade`.
- Define a `to-one` relationship from `WhereItCameFrom` to `Book`. Its deletion rule is `Deny`.

See the diagram:

[image]

I'm wondering if this this the right way to do it and I have a few specific questions.

1) What's the typical way to implement enum with associated values?

I think my above modal is good. But just in case, are there other better ways to do it?

2) Is entity with no attributes normal?

In above diagram, `WhereItCameFrom` doesn't have any attributes. At first I added a `type` attribute to it to indicate if it's a `Bought`, `Borrowed`, or `GivenAsGift` entity. But then I realized this information is implicit in its child entity class type, so I removed it. So the only purpose of the parent entity is to hold the relationship. Is this use typical in Core Data?

3) Will the old object be removed automatically when modifying relationship at run time?

Suppose I modify `book.whereItCameFrom` relationship value at run time. Its previous value is a `Borrowed` object. Its new value is a `GivenAsGift` object. Do I need to delete the `Borrowed` object manually (I mean, doing that explicitly in application code)?

I guess I should do it. But given Core Data is a framework helping to maintain data consistency in object graph, that seems awkward to me. I wonder if Core Data has some feature that can figure out the `Borrowed` object is not needed and delete it automatically?

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:**

In the third question, after the old `Borrowed` object is disconnected with `Book` object, is my understanding correct that, from the `Borrowed` object perspective, the peer object has been delete and hence the peer object's `Cascade` deletion rule is applied to the `Borrowed` object? If so, then it will be deleted automatically. I think the real question here is if deletion rule applies to relationship update or not. I'll do some experiments on this later today.

Comment: I googled the topics I asked above a lot on the net and I'm surprised that I couldn't find any relevant discussion. For example, how to implement enum with associated values in SQL is a common topic on the net (although they don't use that term, which is Swift specific), but googling  "core data enum with associated values" come up with no results. Another example. There are lots of tutorials on the net explaining deletion rule, but none of them talk about what's the exact behavior when removing an object from relationship. Isn't this strange? Or is it just me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts...

> 1) What's the typical way to implement enum with associated values?
>
> I think my above modal is good. But just in case, are there other better ways to do it?

I can't comment on typical ways of implementing enums with associated values, but your model seems to make sense.  One word of caution: if you search StackOverflow for questions regarding entity inheritance, you will find several answers advising against using it.  The way CD implements subentities (at least for SQLite stores) is to add all the attributes of all the subentities to the parent entity SQLite table.  That's handled for you "under the hood" by CoreData, but the SQLite table can potentially end up being very "wide", which can affect performance.  I've never found it an issue, but you might want to have that in mind if you have lots of data and/or the entities are more complex than you indicate in the question.  Subentities can also cause issues in some rare situations - for example, I've seen questions indicating problems with uniqueness constraints.

> 2) Is entity with no attributes normal?

It's unusual, but not a problem.  However, as all three subentities have `date` and `who` attributes, it would be wise to move these from the subentities to the parent `WhereItComeFrom` entity.  (Otherwise, as noted above, your parent entity table will have three columns for `date` (one for each subentity) and three for `who`).

> 3) Will the old object be removed automatically when modifying relationship at run time?

No.  If you modify the `book.whereItCameFrom` relationship value at run time, with a `GivenAsGift` object replacing a `Borrowed` object, CD's graph management will ensure that the `Borrowed` object's `book` property is set to nil.  The cascade rule does not prevent objects being "orphaned" in this way and you must manually delete the `Borrowed` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Your answer to my third question was exactly what I looked for. Thanks! I was aware of the "wide" table issue you pointed that. It doesn't matter for my app because it won't have a lot of data. I asked the second question because I noticed I had quite a few entities having no attributes but just relationship and computed properties. They fell in two categories: a) parent entity to implement enum, which was what was what I asked above, and b) entities to represent complex relationship between two entities. I'll go ahead to implement them and see how it goes.

Comment: Good luck.  (If you have entities with no attributes, just two one-many relationships to two other entities, you can probably replace them with a direct many-many relationship.)

Comment: I know that and I *thought* a lot about it but still think it's better to have an entity to represent relationship because it does some conversion on the fly. It's hard to explain without the context and I can't find a simple example. I think an altenative approach is to extend one of the entity class with an interface similar to the computed properties implemented by the "relationship" entity, but it feels much more natural to me to have an explicit class.